# org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class com.jea.user.User entity with id x exists

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

**PROBLEM**

I have a REST API in Spring Boot with JPA and Spring Security. When I try to delete an existing user object in my database by ID, I get the following error message:

```
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class com.jea.user.User entity with id 3754c59a-20c5-4c6a-8ddd-62fc49809946 exists
```

The ID that I give to the method as a path variable is exactly the same as the ID that I get returned if I GET all users.
In my Java models the ID is saved as an UUID and in the database JPA creates an BINARY(255) column.

**BELOW HERE IS MY JSON USER OBJECT THAT IS IN THE DATABASE**

```
{
    "id": "3754c59a-20c5-4c6a-8ddd-62fc49809946",
    "profilePicture": null,
    "username": "svennieboy",
    "password": "$2a$10$iZBq8gRsIPqYShu03qJ/2Ou4FWpRPMCs4kqrfo9zIcXozchR41yRC",
    "email": "s@live.nl",
    "role": "ROLE_USER",
    "location": null,
    "website": null,
    "biography": null,
    "allTweets": [],
    "recentTweets": [],
    "followers": [],
    "following": []
}
```

**USER MODEL**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

//Removed code for brevity
```

**USER CONTROLLER METHOD**

```
@DeleteMapping("/users/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteUser(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        userService.deleteUser(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("User deleted", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**USER SERVICE METHOD**

```
 public void deleteUser(UUID id){
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
```

**USER REPOSITORY**

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, UUID> {
}
```

Please explane to me what is going wrong, because I am clueless.

Answer (score 3):

I changed my annotations of my ID in the User model to this and now it works!
So hopefully other people will find this answer very usefull.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( generator = "uuid2" )
    @GenericGenerator( name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2" )
    @Column( name = "id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)" )
    private UUID id;
```

Comment: thank you, works for me too. Can you explain why we have to use the generator type uuid2 with a generic one?